# Mesh networking from iOS to Android

Tags: android, ios, frameworks, multipeer-connectivity, mesh-network

Is there any framework that connects an iOS device to an Android device using a mesh network?

There are apps like FireChat that ables users to speak to each other using only Bluetooth and wifi (via Apple's multipeer connectivity framework). But is there any way to connect iOS devices to Android devices using multipeer connectivity of some kind?

I'm trying to build an app like FireChat to be used by some friends here in college, but it needs to connect iOS devices to Android devices. If there would only be iOS devices, multipeer connectivity framework would be just fine, but in this case, I don't know which framework to use in order to connect all these devices.

Comment: you can also try www.bridgefy.me

Answer (score 4):

I believe the [Open Garden SDK](http://opengarden.launchrock.com/?lrRef=6GZHnF) may be able to meet your needs.

Basically it is an SDK for multipeer communication, by the creators of Firechat. And they claim that it is the same technology that Firechat uses, so I believe it will work with Bluetooth.

They also claim it works on Android and iOs, and as Firechat works on Android too now, I would believe that it is true.

Sorry for all the hypotheticals, but I have not been granted access to it yet so I can´t confirm any of these facts.

Comment: As of november 2015, when I asked Open Garden for info on their SDK and their GreenStone, I only was told to just use FireChat.

Comment: @hmijail - I think that the Open Garden SDK and GreenStone is discontinued. The following links are no longer functional - https://opengarden.com/greenstone, https://opengarden.com/sdk, http://opengarden.launchrock.com/?lrRef=6GZHnF

Comment: As much as I know OpenGarden haven't published their cross platform SDK yet. However http://p2pkit.io is published and available for cross platform p2p networking... Disclaimer: i work for Uepaa developing p2pkit for iOS and Android.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, try http://p2pkit.io.

Its a cross platform p2p sdk which allows you to discover, estimate range and exchange information with nearby devices using p2p technologies (WiFi, BLE).

Disclaimer: i work for Uepaa developing p2pkit for iOS and Android.

Comment: The documentation for p2pkit suggests it has a maximum message payload of 440 bytes. Is this accurate?

Comment: Yes, you can send 440 Bytes as part of the discovery info. Please note, this is not intended for messaging. Have a look at the FAQ: http://p2pkit.io/developer/support/faq/#faq-discovery-info

Comment: Thanks. Two further questions. One: Is it correct that message broadcast can occur completely p2p (i.e. no backhaul)? Two: When an app using p2pkit is run on a device for the first time, will it fail to activate properly if no backhaul is available for API key validation? (Context: I'm working on a secure cross-platform PKI/WoT p2p messaging solution, which needs to function without relying on backhaul at any point in the app lifecycle. I'm hoping p2pkit will fit this role.)

Comment: 1st: In general yes, but the cloud can be used in certain cases for optimizing performance (delivering the discovery info faster). In a complete offline scenario, discovery info exchange on certain devices can be slower.
2nd: If the device is offline when p2pkit is enabled the first time, validation will succeed.
Again a reminder that p2pkit should not be used as a offline messaging api. Please also have a look at the documentation here: http://p2pkit.io/developer/.